# How do I get Treeview to work in Microsoft Access 2013 VBA Code, Windows 8?

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview, windows-8.1, ms-access-2013

I have recently installed a compiled Access application on a Windows 8.1 machine running Office 2013, and forms using treeview don't seem to be working. I get the error:

```
 Object or class does not support this set of events.
```

Comment: This is tough without specific object that is giving you an error. Is it MS Access that has VBA code? or application front end using MS Access database backend?

Comment: It is Microsoft Access that has the VBA code. It seems to be a problem with MSCOMCTL.OCX not having the proper tree-view control. I tried the instructions [here](http://thesmileycoder.com/treeview-working-in-access2013/) but it didn't work. @t_m

Comment: Please can you confirm you have the MSCOMCTL.OCX on your machine and it's registered using RegEdit.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem with the following steps:

1. Deleted MSCOMCTL.OCX from \Windows\Syswow64
2. Opened the Access form that was giving me a problem, and Access reinstalled MSCOMCTL.OCX automatically.
3. Opened a command window with the "Run As Administrator" option
4. Navigated to \Windows\Syswow64
5. Ran `regsvr32 /u MSCOMCTL.OCX`
6. Ran `regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX`
7. Reopened Access and it worked!

**Note: You will need to do this in System32, NOT Syswow64 for 64-bit office. Dumb naming standard, I know.**

@t_m , Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Point is: You can no longer operate TreeView in 64 bit Office.